# A5 Printing on A4 with custom flips and unique layout / flow direction

Tags: printing, notes.app, word-processor

How do I get the following print layout?

[image]

I would like to be able to print from anything, be that notes or a website or anything else.

My mac has only the following layout settings none of which satisfy my criteria. Do you know a way?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your drawing indicates you want to use both sides of the paper. a) Do you have a duplex printer, or will you feed the printer manually one sheet at a time? b) What other choices are available in the "Layout" drop-down menu? c) Please show us pictures of the layout dialog with two-sided printing turned on and set to "2 pages per sheet," and d) another pic of the layout dialog with two-sided printing turned on and set to "4 pages per sheet."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica sure, a) I have a duplex printer   b & c) I just updated the images and added a new one.  Layout Direction only seems to make a difference when the pages are 4 pages per sheet but my requirements are two pages per sheet.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica d) added a new picture.  I think I may need something like Boomanga (linux only)

Comment: Thanks. Are any different choices presented when the drop-down is set to "Paper Handling?"

Comment: The order of pages and print odd or even pages only

Comment: Well...I can't do more than agree printing as you desire isn't supported by the standard macOS software. Steve Chambers' answer and Tetsujin's comment seem the avenues you must take to achieve a booklet output.

Comment: Acrobat Reader DC can print booklets, and can print A4 pages shrunk to A5 side by side and front and back.  I think that should satisfy OP's requirements.

Comment: Acrobat Reader looked like it might do the job @HighPerformanceMark, so thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work out like that though!  I need a more customisable ordering for two page duplex printing and it Acrobat doesn't offer it unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a specialized booklet output that you could assemble and then staple in the middle.

That usually requires either a printer with that function built-in (we have these at work) or a specialized "Imposition" program that will send a document like this to a printer that does not have this feature built in.

This is referred to as "imposition." Since your printer does not support imposition  you need to get an application that will impose this particular layout for you and then send it to your printer. Sorry, but I have no idea what form such an app would take, but I do know that such add-ons are available for the likes Adobe InDesign or Quark Express.

Taking a PDF to a printing service provider would work. Office Supply stores often also offer these services.

Comment: thanks so much for the terminology, that may help me source something, I will start a new search

Comment: Good imposition software will also offset each page's content depending on how many sheets you make into each section [so they all line up once they're folded], if you tell it the paper weight. I don't have any specific recommendations as it's far too long since I last worked in the print industry.